# NullPointerException when using Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, nullpointerexception, mockito

I'm trying to create a test using Mockito, however I'm getting a NullPointerException.

The following is the session bean:

```
package edu.city.set.eia.citypress.beans;

import edu.city.set.eia.citypress.model.RegisUser;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;


@Stateless
public class RegisUserFacade extends AbstractFacade<RegisUser> implements RegisUserFacadeLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "citypress_PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }


    public RegisUserFacade() {
        super(RegisUser.class);
    }


    @Override
    public RegisUser findByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery("select r from RegisUser r where username=:username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        RegisUser regisuser;
        try { 
            regisuser = (RegisUser) query.getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            regisuser = null;
        }
        return regisuser;
    }

    @Override
    public RegisUser findByUserPass(String username, String password){
        Query query = this.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("RegisUser.findByUserPass");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        query.setParameter("password", password);
        RegisUser regisuser;

        try { // To prevent javax.persistence.NoResultException
            regisuser = (RegisUser) query.getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            regisuser = null;
        }

        return regisuser;
    }

    @Override
    public RegisUser findByEmail(String email) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select r from RegisUser r where r.email = :email");
        query.setParameter("email", email);
        RegisUser regisuser;
        try { 
            regisuser = (RegisUser) query.getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            regisuser = null;
        }
        return regisuser;
    }
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
package edu.city.set.eia.citypress.mocking.beans;

import edu.city.set.eia.citypress.beans.RegisUserFacade;
import edu.city.set.eia.citypress.model.RegisUser;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class RegisUserTest {

  private final transient EntityManager mockedEm =
          mock(EntityManager.class);
  private final transient Query mockedQuery =
          mock(Query.class);
  private static final String EMAIL = "test_email";
  private static final String INVALID_EMAIL = "test_email_invalid";

  @Before
  public final void setUp() {

    when(mockedEm.createQuery("Select r from RegisUser r where "
            + "r.email = :email")).thenReturn(mockedQuery);

    when(mockedQuery.setParameter("email", EMAIL)).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
    when(mockedQuery.setParameter("email", INVALID_EMAIL)).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
  }

  @Test
  public void testValidEmail() throws Exception {

    final RegisUser expectedUser = new RegisUser();
    expectedUser.setEmail(EMAIL);

    when(mockedQuery.setParameter("email", EMAIL)).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
    when(mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(expectedUser);

    RegisUserFacade bean = new RegisUserFacade();
    bean.setEntityManager(mockedEm);
    RegisUser user = bean.findByEmail(EMAIL);
    assertNotNull(user);
    assertEquals(EMAIL, user.getEmail());
  }

  @Test(expected = Exception.class)
  public void testInValidEmail() throws Exception {
    final RegisUser expectedUser = new RegisUser();
    expectedUser.setEmail(EMAIL);


    when(mockedQuery.setParameter("email", INVALID_EMAIL)).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
    when(mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenThrow(new Exception());

    RegisUserFacade bean = new RegisUserFacade();
    bean.setEntityManager(mockedEm);
    bean.findByEmail(INVALID_EMAIL);
  }
}
```

The error I get is `testValidEmail caused an ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: On which row do you get the exception?

Comment: at RegisUserFacade.findByEmail(RegisUserFacade.java:68)
and
at RegisUserTest.testValidEmail(RegisUserTest.java:43)

Comment: The row numbers aren't helping much when they're not provided with the code...

Comment: the error results the row that I told. Moreover, I've already included the session bean so that you can check the code.. Nevertheless, the problem is too strange and weird :/

Comment: When I copy and paste your RegisUserFacade.java into Eclipse, row 68 only contains a `}`. Is that it? What's on your row 68?

Comment: actually, I'm sorry it's 64.
and I have query.setParameter("email", email); in 64

Comment: @user1064580 Please edit your post with these details, so others don't have to dig through the comments. It will help others to respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mockito, but it looks like your strings do not match. If Mockito is case sensitive, then it would explain why your `query` object is `null`.

```
when(mockedEm.createQuery("select r from RegisUser r where r.email = :email")).thenReturn(mockedQuery);
```

Notice the lowercase "s" in "select", which matches what you have in your bean.

Comment: the lowercase s?? I didn't understand you

Comment: Your bean has "select" and your test has "Select".

Comment: @user1064580 Great! Accepting this answer would make my day :)

Comment: I've been spending hours..! And I really don't know how to thank you. Furthermore this is my final project.. So I believe you can understand how helpful you've been. Thank you once more, you rock!

Comment: @user1064580 Clicking that little check mark by my answer would be a good way to say thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem and I think the issue was more fundamental.  The mockedQuery.setParameter method should modify the mockedQuery in place and not simply return something.  I solved this using the thenAnswer method instead of the thenReturn method.

```
Mockito.when(mockedQuery.setParameter(anyString(), anyString())).then(
  new Answer<Query>() {
    public Query answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      Object[] argumentsToTest = invocation.getArguments();
      if (!"email".equals((String) argumentsToTest[0])) {
        return findUserByIdQuery;
      }
      if (EMAIL.equals((String) argumentsToTest[1])) {
        Mockito.when(mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(expectedUser);
      } else {
        Mockito.when(mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenThrow(new Exception());
      }
      return mockedQuery;
    }
  }
);
```

This way you can put the entire mock into the @Before block and leave the tests to testing behavior.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

If the `NullPointerException` is thrown at `query.setParameter("email", email);`, then `query` is `null`. Maybe you need a terminating `;` in that query string.

Comment: how can I put a terminating in the query string?

Comment: I mean "terminating" as in "ending", "terminating `;` in that query string" as in `"select r from RegisUser r where r.email = :email;"`.

Comment: tried, same error unfortunately :/ keeps saying tha query is null, and this is weird :/

Comment: The `query` object is mocked, so whether or not the `setParameter` method accepts `null` values is irrelevant.